# Angular 2+ Reactive Form - Issue with arrays

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a form defined as:

```
{
  name: [null, Validators.required],
  rows: this.fb.array([])
}
```

I am trying to create a form that consists of one fixed tab (containing the 'name' form-control) and N tabs for each row.

I am facing difficulties while working with the reactive form:

```
<form name="myForm" [formGroup]="myForm" class="editar-form">
    <mat-tab-group>

        <mat-tab label="Main">
            <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput placeholder="Name" formControlName="name" type="text">
            </mat-form-field>

        </mat-tab>

        <mat-tab [label]="'Row ' + (i + 1)" *ngFor="let row of myForm.get('rows').value; let i = index">

**ERROR HERE**  <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput placeholder="Row Id" [formControlName]="'rows[' + i + '].rowId'" type="text">
            </mat-form-field>

        </mat-tab>

    </mat-tab-group>
</form>
```

I tried using formArrayName on the mat-tab, but it failed - browser ran out of memory, that's why I tried using the braces above (which also didn't work).

Any idea on how to implement it?

Comment: you must use a formArray, I put an answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51094563/formarray-usage-and-dynamically-add-row-of-controls/51096087#51096087 wich include a link to the official docs

Comment: @Eliseo if I use a formArray (before the mat-tab) the material tab won't get rendered. An if i put it on the mat-tab, I get the memory error. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

your FormArray is a FormArray of controls or a FormArray of groups?

I show the code using a FromArray of FormGroup (myForm) and using an Array of FormsControls (myForm2). The "key" is the function "rows" that make reference to this.myForm.get('rows').

```
export class TabGroupBasicExample implements OnInit {
  myForm:FormGroup;
  myForm2:FormGroup;

  get rows()
  {
    return this.myForm?(this.myForm.get('rows') as FormArray).controls:[]
  }
  get rows2()
  {
    return this.myForm?(this.myForm2.get('rows') as FormArray).controls:[]
  }
  constructor(private fb:FormBuilder){}
  ngOnInit()
  {

    this.myForm=this.fb.group({
      name:"Step 1",
      rows:new FormArray([])
    });
    this.myForm2=this.fb.group({
      name:"Step 1",
      rows:new FormArray([])
    });
    this.rows.push(this.fb.group({
      value:3
    }))
    this.rows.push(this.fb.group({
      value:2
    }));
    this.rows2.push(new FormControl('uno'));
    this.rows2.push(new FormControl('dos'));
  }
}

// the .html
<mat-tab-group *ngIf="myForm" >
  <mat-tab [label]="myForm.get('name').value"> Content 1 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab *ngFor="let control of rows" [label]="control.get('value').value">
      <pre>{{control.value |json}} </pre>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>

<mat-tab-group *ngIf="myForm2" >
  <mat-tab [label]="myForm2.get('name').value"> Content 1 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab *ngFor="let control of rows2" [label]="control.value"> 
    <pre>{{control.value |json}} </pre>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
<pre>{{myForm?.value |json</pre>
<pre>{myForm2?.value |json</pre>
```

[the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-161pb9?file=app%2Ftab-group-basic-example.html)

Comment: Hi @Eliseo, how would I add a input to the row? My FormArray is an array of FormGroups. I forked your stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-161pb9-yazt77